# File names not sorted

Tags: batch-file

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=xxxxxxxxxxx\"
Test.txt echo !var!
set "var1=$(LOCAL_PATH)/batch/"
set "var2=:/data/local/12m/batch/"
set "var3=$(LOCAL_PATH)/"
set "var4=:/data/local/12m/"

for %%a in (batch/*.bat) do (
    >>Test.txt echo !var1!%%a!var2!%%a \
) 

for %%a in (*.bmp) do (
    >>Test.txt echo !var3!%%a!var4!%%a \
) 

for %%a in (*.wav) do (
    >>Test.txt echo !var3!%%a!var4!%%a \
) 

for %%a in (*.cfg) do (
    >>Test.txt echo !var3!%%a!var4!%%a \
)
```

problem : the filenames should be in sorted order in Test.txt but it is not(The .bat files should be in sorted order followed by .bmp files in sorted order etc). How to fix this?

Note: There is a >> operator in front of Test.txt everywhere but for some reason this editor removed it...  e.g it is >>test.txt echo !var1"

*EDIT by jeb:* You should use code formatting and read the **How to Format** help at the right side.

Thanks
SSE
@jeb : I noticed that the files are sorted if I run the batch file in my local drive/folder and the files are not sorted if I run the batch file in a mapped drive. I need this to work in my mapped drive. Copying contents to individual output files per file type and then copying all the contents to one single file also does not sort files in mapped drive. I am using windows 7. Is this a windows 7 issue? The mapped drive is a map of my local workspace on a linux server. I believe that it follows ext2 file system.

@Niel @Robert Harvey : I tried  `for /F "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /on batch\*.bat') do`, but it does not copy any batch file at all... my output file is empty

Comment: The `*.bat` should be sorted by name and also the `*.bmp`, but obviously they are not sorted over all. Or perhaps I misunderstood your question

Answer (score 1):

`for` doesn't sort your file names. You could create (four) temporary files and sort the result and output that to your final file. Or you could use extended `for` syntax to read the output of `dir/b/o`.

Comment: what type of OS and filesystem you use? I'm nearly sure that my `for` sorts the files

Comment: @jeb if you use NTFS then you get sorting, but only because it happens to be convenient to sort the file names on disk to make them easier to look up. It's not the same sort (!) of sorting as dir/o so that doesn't help you.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your files have numbers as names, then they are also sorted on a stringcompare basis, they aren't sorted numerical.

Sample.
2 is greater then 10, as they are compared as strings.
So a normal (and correct) sorted list could be

- 1
- 10
- 12
- 2
- 20

If your sort fails at another point, please show some samples

Comment: it is not sorted by number... e.g text from my test.txt file - $(LOCAL_PATH)/Grayscale_pattern_main.bmp:/data/local/12m/Grayscale_pattern_main.bmp \
$(LOCAL_PATH)/Color_bar_pattern_main.bmp:/data/local/12m/Color_bar_pattern_main.bmp \ - If you notice, the color_bar_pattern_main.bmp should be listed first

Comment: That's curious, on my Vista system they are always sorted, and also on my XP system it works. Are you on a NTFS partition?

Answer (score 0):

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "var=xx"
>>Test1.txt echo !var!
set "var1=yy"
set "var2=zz"
set "var3=aaa"
set "var4=bb"
set "var5=cc"

for %%a in (batch/*.bat) do (
>>Test2.txt echo !var1!%%a!var2!%%a \
)
for %%a in (*.bmp) do (
>>Test3.txt echo !var3!%%a!var4!%%a \
)
for %%a in (*.wav) do (
>>Test4.txt echo !var3!%%a!var4!%%a \
) 
for %%a in (*.cfg) do (
>>Test5.txt echo !var3!%%a!var4!%%a \
) 
@echo off
sort Test2.txt>>Test1.txt
sort Test3.txt>>Test1.txt
sort Test4.txt>>Test1.txt
sort Test5.txt>>Test1.txt

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>>Test1.txt echo !var5!

del Test2.txt
del Test3.txt
del Test4.txt
del Test5.txt
```

Now am writign to five different files and am sorting each file before appending to the first one. This works for me now. Any sugegestion to improve this code is welcome